# Regex to match english character range between a comma

Tags: c#, regex

I am crrently trying to sort through a file and need a regex for the following scenario:

A line should have the characters from `A-Z a-z 0-9 or " " "_"` then it is going to be separated by a single `,` and then it should match the `A-Z a-z 0-9 or " " "_"` again. But it should not accept a line if there are any other characters before or after it.

So this should be valid:

```
123 45, Amogus
1234, Al Amogus9_
```

But this should be not:

```
1235, AMogus,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
susus
s, s, s
.12, sus.
```

I currently have this regex `[A-Za-z0-9_" "]+,[A-Za-z0-9_" "]+` but unfortunately it does noot exclude any special characters before or after the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for *anchors*, `^` and `$` which mark begin and end of the string:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_ ]+,[A-Za-z0-9_ ]+$
```

here

```
^              - beginning of the string
[A-Za-z0-9_ ]+ - one or more letters, digits, _ or spaces (' ')
,              - comma ','
[A-Za-z0-9_ ]+ - one or more letters, digits, _ or spaces (' ')
$              - end of the string
```

So you have pattern which should match the *whole* string not an arbitrary part of it. Note, that space (`' '`) is an ordinary symbol in regex, no quotation marks are required.

[Fiddle yourself](https://regex101.com/r/enXWU0/1)